# How can we construct multiple Circle PackLayout (basis keys) on predefined x, y location in D3.js?

Tags: d3.js, nested, circle-pack

js experts, Need your help. I have been working hard for last 2 days but could not get thru. I have COVID-19 data grouped by cumulative cases as on month end (28th Feb, 31st Mar & so on). Transformed the x,y location for 9 months as under:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  },
  width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + [width / 2, height / 2] + ")";
  })

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y");
var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%b-%y");

var angleScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI - 0.5])
angleScale.domain([new Date(2020, 2, 1), new Date(2020, 2, 31)])

var radius = width * 0.4

var radiusScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, 100000]);

var data = [];
["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra"].forEach(function(c) {
  var cum = 1;
  var date = new Date(angleScale.domain()[0]);
  while (date <= angleScale.domain()[1]) {
    data.push({
      country: c,
      date: new Date(date),
      // Simulate exponential growth
      cum: Math.floor(cum *= (1 + Math.random() * 0.3)),
    });
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
});

var nestedData = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.date
  })
  .entries(data)

nestedData.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.values - b.values
})

packableData = {
  id: "root",
  values: nestedData
}

var packLayout = d3.pack()
  .size([100, 100])

root = d3.hierarchy({
    values: nestedData
  }, function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .sum(function(d) {
    return d.cum;
  })
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value;
  })

date_location_data = root.leaves()
packLayout(root);

const circle_data = [new Date(2020, 2, 28), new Date(2020, 3, 31), new Date(2020, 4, 30), new Date(2020, 5, 31), new Date(2020, 6, 30), new Date(2020, 7, 31), new Date(2020, 8, 31), new Date(2020, 9, 30), new Date(2020, 10, 16)]

var Maincell = svg.selectAll('.date-group')
  .data(circle_data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", 'date-group')
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var x = radiusScale(90000) * Math.cos(angleScale(d)),
      y = radiusScale(90000) * Math.sin(angleScale(d))
    return "translate(" + [x, y] + ")";
  })

var cell = Maincell
  .selectAll(".node")
  .data(date_location_data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })
  .attr("class", "node")

cell.append("circle")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return "node-" + d.name;
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return "red";
  })
  .style("opacity", 1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The specimen csv file is as:

```
Country,Date,cum
Afghanistan,2/28/20,1
Albania,2/28/20,0
Algeria,2/28/20,1
Andorra,2/28/20,0
....
Yemen,10/16/20,2055
Zambia,10/16/20,15659
Zimbabwe,10/16/20,8099
```

I am getting the circle pack for entire data repeating at all 9 locations. I need your help in such that circle pack for that particular date (28th Feb, 31st Mar) appear at transformed location defined above.

Many thanks,

Comment: Your dates are wrong, Months are 0-indexed, so `new Date(2020, 2, 28)` is actually March, not February

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Please try to visualise what you want and confirm that the sample data I generated is correct for your cause

Comment: Hi Ruben, Many thanks for the efforts. I would like to show country wise cumulative cases at the end of months (28thFeb, 31Mar, 30Apr & so on to see the increase in cases for every country after each month (in a circle pack layout for each month end). I would spread these months-end number on a circle equally spread (9 circle pack layout spread by 40 degrees. The data you pulled is for each date of March, the data we need is at 28th Feb, 31st Mar etc. I will share the csv for 4 countries in following comment. Thank you once again for your time. Appreciated.

Comment: `Country,Date,cum,Month
China,2/28/20,78928,28 Feb
India,2/28/20,3,28 Feb
US,2/28/20,17,28 Feb
China,3/31/20,82279,31 Mar
India,3/31/20,1397,31 Mar
US,3/31/20,192091,31 Mar
China,4/30/20,83956,30 Apr
India,4/30/20,34863,30 Apr
US,4/30/20,1076689,30 Apr
China,5/31/20,84146,31 May
India,5/31/20,190609,31 May
US,5/31/20,1796645,31 May
China,6/30/20,84785,30 Jun
India,6/30/20,585481,30 Jun
US,6/30/20,2633871,30 Jun
China,7/31/20,87655,30 Jul
India,7/31/20,1695988,30 Jul
US,7/31/20,4559711,30 Jul
` and so on for 31 Aug, 30 Sep & 16 Oct